# Обрезать текст регулярным выражением Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток!

Возник вопрос, который никак не могу разрешить, а  именно:
имеется некий .csv файл, со строками:

```
http://fallertoo.com/
http://xn----7sbjsadhgf0dd3k7b.we--p1qw/vse_seeei_podryad/mqwetiki
http://www.nice.com/ru/
http://exway.to/%D0%qwewqeD0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD
http://name@while.com
http://news.t-stilex.into/v-vashem-aktive-net-inostrannyx-yazykov-ne-kruchintes
http://fib.mexeemat.com:80/books/90359
```

необходимо с помощью регулярного выражения вернуть только доменные имена:

```
fallertoo.com
xn----7sbjsadhgf0dd3k7b.we--p1qw
nice.com
exway.to
while.com
t-stilex.into
fib.mexeemat.com
```

возможно, потребуется несколько итераций с разными выражениями, пока я дошел только до варианта `(//\w+.\w+.\w+)`, который возвращает такой результат:

```
//fallertoo.com
//www.nice.com
//exway.to
//name@while.com
//news.t-stilex
//fib.mexeemat.com
```

Просьба помочь, заранее благодарю!

Comment: `re.findall(r'//([^/]*\.[^/:]+)', s)`?

Comment: Спасибо! Там были недочеты, но в итоге получилось!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать

```
re.findall(r'//([^/]*\.[^/:]+)', s)
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/UtEthN/1)

**Подробности**

- `//` - подстрока `//`
- `([^/]*\.[^/:]+)` - Захватывающая группа №1:

  - `[^/]*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от `/`
  - `\.` - точка
  - `[^/:]+` - 1 и более символов, отличных от `/` и `:`.

[Python](https://ideone.com/0HrZ7M):

```
import re
rx = r"//([^/]*\.[^/:]+)"
strs = ["http://fallertoo.com/", "http://xn----7sbjsadhgf0dd3k7b.we--p1qw/vse_seeei_podryad/mqwetiki",
    "http://www.nice.com/ru/", "http://exway.to/%D0%qwewqeD0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD",
    "http://name@while.com", "http://news.t-stilex.into/v-vashem-aktive-net-inostrannyx-yazykov-ne-kruchintes",
    "http://fib.mexeemat.com:80/books/90359"]
for s in strs:
    m = re.search(rx, s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Результат:

```
fallertoo.com
xn----7sbjsadhgf0dd3k7b.we--p1qw
www.nice.com
exway.to
name@while.com
news.t-stilex.into
fib.mexeemat.com
```

Comment: спасибо за подробный ответ!